# How to use observable and pipes in a function rxjs?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

Im trying to get this following code to move into a function that's called rather than doing it from a native element click event:

```
const saveRit$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.saveRitbutton.nativeElement, 'click');
console.log('here', saveRit$);
saveRit$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.account$)
).subscribe(([click, { accountId }]) => {
  console.log('working');
  this.saveRit(accountId).then(() => {
    const years = this.ritForm.controls['lineItems'].value.map(row => row.year);
    this.emitSuccess(years);
  });
});
```

I have limited knowledge on pipes and observable so any input is amazing. I know I no longer need the `saveRit$` variable however I am at a loss as to what to do `.pipe()` to once it's removed? I just want to be able to call this from some function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Observable.fromEvent just gives you an Observable we could replace it with any other Observable. As far as I can see from your snippet you want to subscribe on `this.account$`.

```
this.account$.subscribe(account => {
  console.log('working');
  this.saveRit(account.accountId).then(() => {
    const years = this.ritForm.controls['lineItems'].value.map(row => row.year);
    this.emitSuccess(years);
  });
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Mate, you're an absolute legend, thank you so much, I need to brush up on this stuff, I was assuming an observable similar to `saveRit$` was needed to I was using `Observable.Empty()` ... Anyway, thank you so much!